# What is the use of dispatch in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to follow up Brad Travery tutorial of MERN stack. And he uses dispatch function most of the time when working with redux.

Here is userAction.js for instance,

```
 import axios from 'axios'
 import { USER_LOGIN_FAIL, USER_LOGIN_REQUEST, USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS } from '../constants/userConstants'

 export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST
    })

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    const { data } = await axios.post('/api/users/login', {email, password}, config)

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
    })

    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message,
    })
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dispatch` takes an action and "gives" it to the redux store, which in turn results in the redux store executing the reducers and leading to a change in the store.

That said, that tutorial you are following is teaching a horrible outdated style of Redux. Modern Redux looks very different - please follow [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [core concepts](https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts)

`dispatch` just runs the action